# Read an excel file and update webpage information?[HTML]

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have doubts on how this can be achieved, the language I'm using is HTML and some javascript, but what I want is to read an excel file, on this case, languages, and update the webpage depending on whats chosen(English, Spanish, etc).

For example:

[image]

What I want is the website to update when Spanish or English or any other language is chosen:

banner:

[image]

Right now it changes but it's done with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the Excel file and you don't have super fancy formattings in the Excel file, you can save the file as a CSV (comma-separated values) and parse it with JS. CSV is quite easy to parse, but there are libraries such as [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/) that you can utilize.

Usually, CSV files are delimited using return characters `\n` (sometimes `\r\n`, [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2)) for rows and commas `,` for columns.

Here's a rough sketch of what you're trying to achieve with no libraries:

```js
// Whichever way you end up with getting the CSV as a string
let csvFile = fetch("lang.csv").then(x => x.text()); 

    csvFile = csvFile.split("\r\n").map( x => x.split(",") );

// Assuming your field name is the element ID you want to replace the text with.
function selectLanguage(lang) {
    if (lang == "") return;

    let langRowNum = csvFile.some( (row, index) => {
        langRowNum = index;
        return row[0] == lang; // see if the first cell of the row is matching
    })? langRowNum : 1; // default to Espanol

    // assuming first row is the ID of the elements
    for (let i = 1; i < csvFile[0].length; ++i)
        document.getElementById(csvFile[0][i]).textContent = csvFile[langRowNum][i]
}

selectLanguage("English");
```

---

Excel should allow you to save files as CSV:

[image: excel screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

you can't process an excel file without the help of a server side language. browsers are [sand-boxed](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-web-browser-sandbox). so it can't use libraries other than it's own.

**but you can achieve what you want with a help of a .JSON file** which contain the settings you want.

JSON is a better file type/ Format to store and exchange data in JavaScript.

[this article](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-load-data-from-a-JSON-file-into-a-variable-in-JavaScript-without-using-Ajax) will teach you how to do so.

Comment: i do know this, it was just for a project that the teacher was asking for this excel file. at the end i used just a macro that generates that json file